# Round down value when importing from txt file to excel with vba

Tags: excel, vba, rounding, trim

I am trying to import values from txt files, the script works but, except I would like to trim the value's back to one digit after decimal point. This is what I's got so far:

```
Sub ExtractSizeTXT()
    Dim filename As String, nextrow As Long
    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim text As String
    Dim xPosBeginText As Long, xTextLength As Long, yPosBeginText As Long, yTextLength As Long
    Dim xPlaceholder1 As String, xPlaceholder2 As String, yPlaceholder1 As String, yPlaceholder2 As String
    Dim oWS As Worksheet
    
    xPlaceholder1 = "AAA"
    xPlaceholder2 = "BBB"
    yPlaceholder1 = "CCC"
    yPlaceholder2 = "DDD"
    Set oWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ExtractSizeTXT")
    MyFolder = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\TXT\"
    MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "*.txt")


    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ExtractSizeTXT").Range("A2:A" & Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ExtractSizeTXT").Range("B2:B" & Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ExtractSizeTXT").Range("C2:C" & Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents
    End With
    
        Do While MyFile <> ""
        Open (MyFolder & MyFile) For Input As #1
        Do Until EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, text
            xPosBeginText = InStr(1, text, xPlaceholder1, vbTextCompare)
            yPosBeginText = InStr(1, text, yPlaceholder1, vbTextCompare)
            
            nextrow = oWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            ' process only if Placeholder1 was found
            If xPosBeginText > 0 Then
                xPosBeginText = xPosBeginText + Len(xPlaceholder1)            ' Add length of placeholder1 to start
                xTextLength = Len(text) - xPosBeginText - Len(xPlaceholder2)    ' Get length of text
                oWS.Cells(nextrow, "A").Value = Left(MyFile, InStr(MyFile, ".") - 1)                 ' Add file name
                oWS.Cells(nextrow, "B").Value = Trim(Mid(text, xPosBeginText, xTextLength)) ' Add text from the line
            End If
            If yPosBeginText > 0 Then
                yPosBeginText = yPosBeginText + Len(yPlaceholder1)            ' Add length of placeholder1 to start
                yTextLength = Len(text) - yPosBeginText - Len(yPlaceholder2)    ' Get length of text
                oWS.Cells(nextrow - 1, "C").Value = Trim(Mid(text, yPosBeginText, yTextLength)) ' Add text from the line
            End If
        Loop
        Close #1
        MyFile = Dir()
    Loop
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ExtractSizeTXT").Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
End Sub
```

I've tried to add Round here:
`oWS.Cells(nextrow, "B").Value = Round(Trim(Mid(text, xPosBeginText, xTextLength)), 1)`

But that's doesn't work properly; the original to be imported value is: "216,450825" But the result I get is: "216450825". What I would like to import is: "216,4"

Comment: Round is also VBA function @Blackcat

Comment: There is no rule to round 216,450825 to 216,4. 216,4 is the absolutely wrong value. The correct value is 216,5. With some rules 216,4500000... can be rounded to 216,4 but not 216,450825.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim filename As String, nextrow As Long
    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim text As String
    Dim xPosBeginText As Long, xTextLength As Long, yPosBeginText As Long, yTextLength As Long
    Dim xPlaceholder1 As String, xPlaceholder2 As String, yPlaceholder1 As String, yPlaceholder2 As String
    Dim oWS As Worksheet
    
    xPlaceholder1 = "AAA"
    xPlaceholder2 = "BBB"
    yPlaceholder1 = "CCC"
    yPlaceholder2 = "DDD"
    Set oWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ExtractSizeTXT")
    MyFolder = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\TXT\"
    MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "*.txt")


    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ExtractSizeTXT").Range("A2:A" & Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ExtractSizeTXT").Range("B2:B" & Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ExtractSizeTXT").Range("C2:C" & Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents
    End With
    
        Do While MyFile <> ""
        Open (MyFolder & MyFile) For Input As #1
        Do Until EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, text
      

  text = Trim(text)
            xPosBeginText = InStr(1, text, xPlaceholder1, vbTextCompare)
            yPosBeginText = InStr(1, text, yPlaceholder1, vbTextCompare)
                        nextrow = oWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            ' process only if Placeholder1 was found
            If xPosBeginText > 0 Then
                xPosBeginText = xPosBeginText + Len(xPlaceholder1)            ' Add length of placeholder1 to start
                xTextLength = Len(text) - xPosBeginText - Len(xPlaceholder2)    ' Get length of text
                oWS.Cells(nextrow, "A").Value = Left(MyFile, InStr(MyFile, ".") - 1)                 ' Add file name
                
                oWS.Cells(nextrow, "B").Value = Mid(text, xPosBeginText, xTextLength) ' Add text from the line
            End If
            If yPosBeginText > 0 Then
                yPosBeginText = yPosBeginText + Len(yPlaceholder1)            ' Add length of placeholder1 to start
                yTextLength = Len(text) - yPosBeginText - Len(yPlaceholder2)    ' Get length of text
                oWS.Cells(nextrow - 1, "C").Value = Trim(Mid(text, yPosBeginText, yTextLength)) ' Add text from the line
            End If
        Loop
        Close #1
        MyFile = Dir()
    Loop
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ExtractSizeTXT").Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
```

'text = Trim(text) added before calculate xPosBeginText it's working for me please check and reply.

Answer (score -1):

You don't state your problem in details. So, I can guess.

You can round the number, but it will not display correctly due to the knowing problem with binary representation of floating-point numbers. Despite rounding you need to format the cell to display the number with required number of digits after the decimal dot.

But the latest release of Microsoft Excel perfectly processes such situations and displays numbers as accurate as possible.

**UPD** Your problem is not related to rounding but to regional settings. Your current decimal separator is dot, but you try to process a number in the text representation with the comma decimal separator. Round behaves exactly as you described:

```
?Round("216,450825", 1)
216450825
```

You need to replace the comma by the dot:

```
?Round(Replace("216,450825", ",", "."), 1)
216.5
```

In reverse settings (process dot-delimited number's text with comma settings) Excell raise the type mismatch error (13).

If you need to floor numbers instead of round, use WorksheetFunction.Floor_Precise function:

```
?WorksheetFunction.Floor_Precise(Replace("216,450825", ",", "."), 0.1)
216.4
```

Comment: `Round` is buggy and also performs _Banker's Rounding_, thus it returns 216.5, not the reuested value rounded down: 216.4.

Comment: @Gustav there is no rule to round 216,450825 to 216,4. 216,4 is the absolutely wrong value. The correct value is 216,5. With some rules 216,4500000... can be rounded to 216,4 but not 216,450825.

Comment: Sorry, you have been misguided. There are, of course, strict rules for rounding, and four methods are in common use: _Round Up_, _Round Down_, _Round Mid_ (4/5 rounding), and _Banker's Rounding_ (round to even).  Here, Round Down with one decimal returns the correct result (216,4) as requested by the questioneer.

Comment: @Gustav can you prove your statement? The only breakpoint is exactly 0.5. Rounding 216,450825 to 1 digit after the decimal point, 0.50825 should be rounded up with no variants.

Comment: That is right - if you do a "normal" rounding by 4/5 as we learned in school. But the questioneer asks specifically for a round (down) to 216.4 which, effectively, means to _chop_ the remaining decimals: 0.050825. And that is exactly what `Int` is for and does.  Its counterpart `Fix` rounds the _absolute_ value down which makes no difference for positive value but does for negative values, where `Int(-216.450825 * 10) / 10` will return -216.5, while `Fix(-216.450825 * 10) / 10` will return -216,4.

Comment: @Gustav that you are talking about is knowing as Floor operation. Don't misuse terms. Don't substitute that the questioner asked by that you want to say.

Comment: Floor is a very old name for a function that performs rounding down, as Celing is for rounding up. The question is very clear: _What I would like to import is: "216,4"_, so it should be obvious, that Round is not suitable as it will not return that value. If still in doubt, do read up on Rounding - a good place to start is here: [Rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding).

Comment: @Gustav round/floor/ceiling reflects required action more precise in the discussed area. And questioner is not able to express its requirement without contradictions as well as identify the problem.

Answer (score -1):

First convert to number with `CCur`, then round down with `Int`:

```
oWS.Cells(nextrow, "B").Value = Int(CCur(Trim(Mid(text, xPosBeginText, xTextLength))) * 10) / 10
```

If you setting for the decimal separator is a *dot*, replace the *comma*:

```
oWS.Cells(nextrow, "B").Value = Int(CCur(Replace(Trim(Mid(text, xPosBeginText, xTextLength)), ",", ".")) * 10) / 10
```

For extended rounding methods, see my repository [VBA.Round](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Round).

Comment: It's not related to the problem

Comment: @rotabor: You are right. I've added the correct method.

Comment: WorksheetFunction.Floor_Precise floors the number: ?WorksheetFunction.Floor_Precise("216,450825", 0.1) --> 216,4